# Default log4j policy

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to understand how `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` determines when a log file is created/appended/deleted.

For the below configuration :

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="test" fileName="/logs/test.log" filePattern="/logs/test.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
<Policies>
 <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</Policies>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

Is this correct:

The `%d` parameter indicates a new log files test.log appended with the current `{yyyy-MM-dd}` is created every day ? Previous versions of test.log are not deleted ? If I changed %d to %M should a new file be created every month ?

In order to ensure just the current day log file is avaialable and other log files are deleted the should the policy be amended to :

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="test" fileName="/logs/test.log" filePattern="/logs/test.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
<Policies>
 <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
</Policies>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

?

Comment: Are you looking to have no rollover policy/ triggering policy ? only keep today's file ?

Comment: @s7vr I should have said , I’m just trying to understand some config I’ve encountered . I’m don’t know what the expected result of above config is, from what I know I’ve shared , I’m requesting confirmation of my understanding

Comment: Thanks - I've added answer. I can further expand the answer based on your feedback.

Comment: Don't feel obliged to reply to my comment. If you could what may be the reason for picking other answer for bounty -  just for my understanding so I can provide better answers in the future. Also noticed you didn't accept the answer. Perhaps you are looking for more info ?

Comment: @s7v4 my apologies, I attempted to split the bounty but I cannot edit once its awarded.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to understand how TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy determines when
> a log file is created/appended/deleted.

`TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` controls when the next rollover occurs. The next rollover time is determined based on the date unit provided. `{yyyy-MM-dd}` means it is next day. With no other trigger policy, all the logs are appended to the current day file.

`DefaultRolloverStrategy` controls when the logs files are archived/deleted/created based on the file pattern. When the next day arrives, new file with current date will be created and all the logs are appended to new file. Depending on the rollover strategy configuration the previous day file can be retained or removed. `max` and `min` attributes controls the number of files with `%i` specifier in the file pattern to maintain the file counter and `fileIndex` to control the file renaming.

**Original**

> The %d parameter indicates a new log files test.log appended with the
> current {yyyy-MM-dd} is created every day ? Previous versions of
> test.log are not deleted ? If I changed %d to %M should a new file be
> created every month ?

`%d` is conversion specifier - Log4j 2 has converters for different conversion specifiers. `%d` refers to date and allows you to send date format. Datetime unit itself controls when the rollover should happen. `%m` is not recognized in log4j2 instead you would use `%d{yyyy-MM}` to create file every month. You can use `modulate` flag to roll over the file at the interval boundary - start of the month.

> In order to ensure just the current day log file is avaialable and
> other log files are deleted the should the policy be amended to :
>
> <RollingRandomAccessFile name="test" fileName="/logs/test.log"
> filePattern="/logs/test.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}" 
> TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/> 
> /RollingRandomAccessFile> ?

Yes, it is correct. `interval="1"` is default so can be removed. `DefaultRollOverStrategy` is applied when you don't specify any rollover strategy. Default Rollover strategy will use the file name pattern provided to roll over. As this is daily (`-dd`) it will roll over file daily with no intermediate files on same day.

From [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) -

> A RollingRandomAccessFileAppender requires a TriggeringPolicy and a
> RolloverStrategy. The triggering policy determines if a rollover
> should be performed while the RolloverStrategy defines how the
> rollover should be done. If no RolloverStrategy is configured,
> RollingRandomAccessFileAppender will use the DefaultRolloverStrategy

You can further customize using appropriate trigger policy and rollover strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Among others, when you configure a [`RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) you need to provide a value for the `filePattern` parameter.

This configuration parameter will indicate the pattern of the file name of the generated archived log files.

The format of this pattern is dependent on the `RolloverPolicy` that is used by `RollingFileAppender`.

By default, Log4j 2 will use the [Default Rollover Strategy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#Default_Rollover_Strategy).

This strategy will allow you to rollover your logs based on a numeric index, by indicating the `%i` pattern token or by date/time, by indicating the `%d` pattern token as in your use case. You can add the numeric index to the date/time pattern as well: in that case, the numeric index will be incremented until the result of the date/time pattern changes.

If you define a date/time pattern, you need to provide the *base* granularity for which the rollover will be performed, by passing a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) compatible pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd` in your example.

I said *base* granularity and not just granularity because the actual log rollover moment will depend on how you configure the trigger policy associated with the `RollingFileAppender`.

In the case of [`TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#TimeBased_Triggering_Policy) you can configure several parameters that will determine the log rollover behavior, mainly two.

First, you have the `interval` parameter: it will indicate how often a rollover should occur based on the *most specific time unit* in the date pattern. i.e. if, as in your example, you configure day as your most specific unit and provide a value of `3` (it is `1` by default) for the `interval` parameter the rollover would occur every `3` days.

Second, you can activate (it is `false` by default) the `modulate` parameter. This parameter indicates whether the interval should be adjusted to cause the next rollover to occur on the interval boundary. The Log4j2 documentation provides a clear example:

> For example, if the item is hours, the current hour is 3 am and the interval is 4 then the first rollover will occur at 4 am and then next ones will occur at 8 am, noon, 4pm, etc.

Something similar will occur in your use case but with the semantic of day of year.

Please, see the [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/913e87d7747aa8d90b7bd3236c4dca2e3307336a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/PatternProcessor.java#L143-L230) of the `PatternProcessor` class for an in-depth information. Pay attention to the [`increment` method](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/913e87d7747aa8d90b7bd3236c4dca2e3307336a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/PatternProcessor.java#L251-L254) as well.

Regarding log deletion, as far as I know the default rollover strategy will only delete old files if you are using a numeric index in your pattern (by tweaking the `fileIndex`, `min` end `max` parameters) but, since Log4j 2.5, you can use the [delete action](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#Log_Archive_Retention_Policy:_Delete_on_Rollover) to perform cleanup of your date/time based logs when the log rollover occurs (in Log4j think in actions as a kind of hook).

For example, if you only need to keep your log files for `30` days you can configure this feature with something like:

```xml
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="test" fileName="/logs/test.log" filePattern="/logs/test.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
  <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    <Delete basePath="/logs">
      <IfFileName glob="test.log.*" />
      <IfLastModified age="30d" />
    </Delete>
  </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

It is very important to be aware that the deletion process can affect to any files, not only log files: please, be sure to parameterize the right path in which it should be performed and to provide the right `glob` pattern when you use this feature.

Comment: Thank you very much for the bounty @blue-sky. I hope the answer was helpful.